# Dbup custom script provider - need to prepend value to journal script names

Tags: sql-server, dbup

I am creating a custom ScriptProvider implementing the IScriptProvider interface in dbup, and I am able to get a list of scripts using the `GetScripts()` method, and return a `SqlScript` object. I would like to compile the object first, and then prior to returning it, modify the name of each script, prepending the current release to the file name that gets inserted into the journal table.

My understanding is that this should be doable, since the content of the script is already added to the `SqlScript` object when its populated, it seems like modifying the name at that point wouldn't affect anything.

The issue I'm having is that the `Name` property of the SqlScript object is read only, so I can't modify it directly as I'd like.

How can I get around this, or is there another way that I could compile the scripts to be executed and journaled, and then prior to writing the script names to the journal table, prepend a value to the script name.

For example, `Script001` becomes `Release 1.0.0 - Script001`.

I would also need to be able to remove this value when reading the previously executed scripts to ensure they match the actual file names and don't get executed again.

**UPDATE**

```
namespace DbUpManifest
{
public class DeploymentManifestScriptProvider : IScriptProvider
{
    readonly string directoryPath;
    readonly string basePath;
    readonly Func<string, bool> filter;
    readonly Encoding encoding;
    readonly FileSystemScriptOptions options;
    public string Release;
    public List<string> FileList;        


    public DeploymentManifestScriptProvider(string basePath, string directoryPath, FileSystemScriptOptions options) 
    {
        if (options == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("options");
        this.options = options;
        this.directoryPath = directoryPath;
        this.basePath = basePath;
    }

    private List<string> SerializeJsonFile()
    {
        Manifest manifest;
        var files = new List<string>();

        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(directoryPath))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            manifest = (Manifest)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(Manifest));
        }

        Release = manifest.Release.ToString();

        foreach (var item in manifest.Scripts)
        {
            string thisItem;
            if(Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                thisItem = string.Concat(basePath, @"Deployment Scripts\vNext\", item);
            }
            else
            {
                thisItem = string.Concat(basePath, @"Deployment Scripts\", Release, @"\", item);
            }

            FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(thisItem);

            foreach (var scriptExtension in options.Extensions)
            {
                if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
                {
                    files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(thisItem, scriptExtension, ShouldSearchSubDirectories()));
                }
                else
                {
                    files.Add(thisItem.ToString());
                }
            }
        }


        foreach (var item in manifest.StoredProcedures)
        {
            string thisItem = string.Concat(basePath, "Stored Procedures", "\\", item);

            FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(thisItem);

            foreach (var scriptExtension in options.Extensions)
            {
                 files.Add(thisItem.ToString());
            }
        }

        return files;
    }        

    public IEnumerable<SqlScript> GetScripts(IConnectionManager connectionManager)
    {
        List<string> scripts = SerializeJsonFile();

        var outputFiles = scripts.Select(x => SqlScript.FromFile(x))
           .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
           .ToList();

        return outputFiles;
    }

    SearchOption ShouldSearchSubDirectories()
    {
        return options.IncludeSubDirectories ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
    }
}
```

}

I've tried modifying this to add the release to the file name, but then it errors saying it can't find the file because the physical file is actually not named with the string prepended.

```
var outputFiles = scripts.Select(x => SqlScript.FromFile(String.Concat(Release," - ", x)))
       .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
       .ToList();
```

I ultimately want to have a manifest file that runs deployment scripts as "run once" type scripts, and then I want to maintain a single version of things like stored procs and views, and have the manifest file dictate which of those scripts get run on each deployment so we're not dropping and recreating every single stored proc, which is what we're currently doing.

The problem is, I have the choice of either using a NullJournal and not writing anything to the DB, or the stored procs won't execute more than once because they will always be named the same.

Trying to think of other ways to accomplish this as well, but so far I've got nothing.

In a perfect world I'd like to be able to have the physical file `dbo.StoredProcedure.sql` get journaled as `Release 1.0.0 - dbo.StoredProcedure.sql`.  That way if that sproc changes in the future, it would get executed and stored as `Release 2.0.0 - dbo.StoredProcedure.sql` or whatever release it's in. But the physical file is always only one file with the same name across time/releases.

Comment: Are you creating your own `SqlScript` objects in your custom provider? The `Name` property can only be set on construction https://github.com/DbUp/DbUp/blob/master/src/dbup-core/Engine/SqlScript.cs

Comment: @StewartRitchie so how would I override this, or am I up a creek?

Comment: Can you share the code you have for your custom script provider? You should be implementing your own version of `GetScripts`, and when you create new `SqlScript` objects, you can just set the name to whatever you want.

Comment: @StewartRitchie - I added my ScriptProvider code and what I tried to modify to accomplish the desired result.

Comment: @StewartRitchie - perhaps I need to add like, a custom journal extension or something. It seems like the SqlScript.Name needs to be the physical file name, and you can't modify it after, but if I could tie in at the point of journaling the scripts and somehow add the value there that could work...no idea how to do that though.

Comment: Instead of using the factory method `SqlScript.FromFile(x)` just create new SqlScript objects (you'll have to read the file contents yourself) e.g. `x => new SqlScript(x, contents)` - That way you can set any name for the script you want

Comment: For the second part of the problem, you'll be reading a mixture of naming styles from the Journal table and matching these against the new naming style - so yes, I believe you'll have to override the way this matching is done - this happens in the `UpgradeEngine` https://github.com/DbUp/DbUp/blob/master/src/dbup-core/Engine/UpgradeEngine.cs#L141